How to edit bundle.yaml before juju deploy
Take"ubuntu 20.04 & openstack ussuri, using openstack base #79" as example
download bundle and charm on MAAS, juju deloy like "offline"
Edit bundle.yaml as follow:
name: openstack-base        
series: focal               *//focal means ubuntu 20.04*
variables:   
  openstack-origin:&openstack-origin cloud:focal-yoga   *//set to cloud:focal-yoga*
  data-port: &data-port br-ex:eno1        *//set to br-ex:eno1, also create bridge "br-ex" on MAAS UI*
  osd-devices: &osd-devices /dev/sdb /dev/sdc    *//ceph node has /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc*
  expected-osd-count:&expected-osd-count 3   
  expected-mon-count: &expected-mon-count 3

applications:
  ceph-mon:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '790'
      gui-y: '1540'
    charm: /home/huawei/openstack-base-yoga-79/ceph-mon       *//change to "charm path" on MAAS,already downloaded*
    channel: quincy/stable          *//delete this line, delete this channel define*
    num_units: 3
    options:
      expected-osd-count: *expected-osd-count
      monitor-count: *expected-mon-count
      source: *openstack-origin
    to:
    - lxd:1
    - lxd:2
    - lxd:3

any thing else need to be modify or delete?
